# Postponing internship confirmation from Student end

Tags: research-undergraduate, internship

I have received an exciting research internship offer from a professor but have simultaneously applied for certain funded research internship programs as well whose results I am awaiting.
I want to let the professor know that in spite of my interest in working with them, I first want to weigh all my options and choose the best from them in terms of opportunity, experience, and funding. I want to convey to the professor that although I am thankful for the opportunity I can let them know my confirmation to the internship only at a later date. Can someone suggest to me a polite way to do this?

The internship is from May and I can confirm only by March 2021.

Comment: How long do you expect to need before you can confirm? Is it a couple of days or more like a month or maybe even longer?

Comment: Do you know this professor personally? If so, can you meet with them face to face?

Comment: @Buffy I do not know the professor personally, I had mailed them for an internship after checking their research interests on the institution website, and am from a different country. However, coincidently the professor had previously collaborated with a professor whom I am currently working with.

Comment: I suggest asking your professor how to approach the other. Most (I hope) of us will understand your desires/needs and accommodate them if possible and if other things (deadlines) don't get in the way.